# How to join values of map in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pattern-matching, python-module

This is a .py file for pattern matching problem:

```
import sys
def pattern_matching(pattern,genome):
    loc = []
    for i in range(len(genome) - len(pattern) + 1):
        if  pattern == genome[i:i+len(pattern)]:
            loc.append(i)
    return loc
if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) == 2:
        filename = sys.argv[1]
        with open(filename) as f:
            lines = f.read().splitlines()
        pattern = lines[0]
        genome = lines[1]
    else:
        pattern = 'ATAT'
        genome = 'GATATATGCATATACTT'
    loc = pattern_matching(pattern,genome)
  print ",".join(map(str,loc))
```

But it's showing an error called "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" for line 22. How to print the result?

Comment: The issue is probably your incorrect indentation of line 22, or depending on your version it's the non encapsulated `print` statement

Comment: @ChrisCharley wouldn't throw `Syntax` error if that were the case and in any matter, `map` takes an itterable

Comment: `print` become a function in python3.x, you must use it like this: `print(xxx)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert to a list will be ok.

```py
 print(",".join(list(map(str,loc))))
```

In python2.x, map function return a list which return a map object in python3.x, so you neect to convert the return of map function to a list.

Answer (score 0):

Fix the `Unexpected Unindenting` and encapsulate the `print()` statement if your on a version `> python3`

```
import sys
def pattern_matching(pattern,genome):
    loc = []
    for i in range(len(genome) - len(pattern) + 1):
        if  pattern == genome[i:i+len(pattern)]:
            loc.append(i)
    return loc
if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) == 2:
        filename = sys.argv[1]
        with open(filename) as f:
            lines = f.read().splitlines()
        pattern = lines[0]
        genome = lines[1]
    else:
        pattern = 'ATAT'
        genome = 'GATATATGCATATACTT'
    loc = pattern_matching(pattern,genome)
    print(",".join(map(str,loc))) # Corrected unindent and encapsulated print
```